# Oracle Weird error : Unexpected error ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00937

Oracle Weird error : Unexpected error ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Executing from VB6 Application, using Adodb using Provider=MSDAORA.1

Query:

```
Select Max(SNO) as SRNO 
  From Orders 
 Where OrderDate = '30-Jan-2009'
```

Error:

> Unexpected error ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

As per my knowledge this error should be fired only if the query contains an aggregate function, while the selected columns not in the aggregate function, then these columns must be in the Group By clause.

Now in my query, there is no extra column selected.

More weird:

If the same query is executed in the oracle SQL Plus it works. But gives above error if executed from VB6. Any hints

I have worked around `MAX` using rownum and inner query.

```
select SRNO  
  from (Select SNO as SRNO 
          From Orders 
         Where OrderDate = '08/Dec/2009'  
      order by SNO  desc ) 
 where RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Extra tip, totally unrelated, but important nonetheless: use dates when comparing with date columns. So better use `date '2009-01-30'` or `to_date('30-Jan-2009','dd-Mon-yyyy','nls_date_language=american')`, instead of `'30-Jan-2009'`.

Answer (score 1):

Could be bug 1988231 if you have `CURSOR_SHARING` set to `FORCE` or `SIMILAR`, which is a problem with the Microsoft drivers and databases up to 10.2.0.4. Advice seems to be to set `CURSOR_SHARING` to `EXACT` (the default I think), or switch to use an Oracle ODBC driver.

(The bug itself is closed as not-a-bug (since it's a Microsoft issue not an Oracle one), and it's referenced from Metalink document ID 462734.1).

Comment: Thanks for giving this corner case. I would not be able to test the same for some time as it is at client location and they have started processing their pending jobs. I have upoted. Once tested I will mark accepted.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a bug in ADO provider, if you change provider to OraOLEDB.Oracle - than query should work

Comment: This is VB6. It dont have OraOLEDB.Oracle

Comment: "using Adodb using Provider=MSDAORA.1"  -> change Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1  (you can install it with oracle client)